# Do other resources exist on Rate-Independent Systems?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, discrete-time

Are Rate Independent System new in the world of mathematics? I can't tell because I certainly am new to mathematics.
I couldn't find any more resources than this book:
[Rate-Independent Systems: Theory and Application](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1493947834).
Googling only shows some excerpts by the same author

Please give me some books ( maybe something lighter) on this topic or something similar on this topic as I am having difficulty understanding the subject from the current text due to my prior lack of involvement with rigorous math texts

The kind of problems —
Excerpt from the book:

[Sweeping Bowl1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxDhV.jpg)

[Sweeping Bowl2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV0Vi.jpg)

Comment: If you are not familiar with math texts, it seems quite ambitious to read math texts on rate-independent systems, since they are (from a mathematical point of view) quite challenging. What is your education and what is your goal?

Comment: I am a first year student of applied mathematics and I have recently developed interest in this field. I do have some knowledge of mathematical analysis and am familiar with rigorous proofs. I want to study Rate Independent Systems to advance my knowledge in modeling. Aiming at the stars actually. I wouldn't mind if I just reach the moon.Can you please recommend something on this subject?

Comment: The first excerpt from the book shows that the authors try to introduce new people into the field. I'd like to see more of it. So awaiting your findings/questions while you keep aiming at the stars. The first author [Alexander Mielke](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Mielke) has a german WP article. There does not seem to exist an english version, nor an article devoted to Rate-Independent Systems. This tells me that that book might be one of the few ways to go.

Comment: @KurtG. So it's a new field after all. Glad that it exists. Please do comment if you ever find something related to this someday

Comment: The next standard source are articles like [arxiv.org/abs/2010.00314](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.00314) or AM's university [home page](https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/mielke/index.jsp). If it is true that this is about non-linear dynamical systems be prepared for a bumpy ride.